# How do I accept github collaborator invite

Tags: github

Truly, I received a mail of invite to which I click on the button. But this link to the repo manage access page where there no button or link to accept or decline. Plus there was no notification in my github account.

Yes, I have received the invite mail, but I will appreciate any solution on how to accept the invitation. Thank you

Comment: So if you got access to github, then just pull repo and start working

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Regarding github.com, [Thomas Dohmke (now CEO of GitHub) is clear](https://twitter.com/ashtom/status/1458164550717509634), since Nov. 2021:

> We improved @github repo invites and shipped three small changes to make them easier to discover:
>
> 1. navigating to a private repo with a pending invite no longer ends in a 404, but prompts you to accept the invitation.
>
> [image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FDxw7eLUYAIJ-ap?format=jpg&name=large]
>
> 2. you will now receive notifications for private repo invites as you already do for public repos.
>
> [image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FDxxI6UUcAEjqZn?format=jpg&name=large]
>
> 3. in case of a pending invite on a public repo, you will now see a banner pointing you to accept the invite.
>
> [image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FDxxZ_PVgAE-AfL?format=jpg&name=large]

Make sure you are logged in `github.com` first.

Comment: your last comments solved it. I have forgotten to sign out from the repo i sent invite from. i send the invite from my organization repo to personal.